# SQLITE with Cordova

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have a problem about sqlite with cordova. 
I can't access to my database in each page except index page.(the database is already created)
 I didn't found any topic that can help me. 
my problem is : 
this is
[my js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwQt6.png)

The last alert that I showed is at line 16, I just tried to open my database and it doesn't work.( also I added reference to cordova.js in my html page )

Comment: We need to see portion of code having problem

Comment: Thank you for your response
Open my js file , it shows all javascript file, and check line 17 i think that is the source of my problem .

Comment: donot declare var db , inside the onDeviceready , just say db = ...; make var db as global variable . This should solve the problem .Hope it helps. Respond if it does or doesnot. Also include index.js in all your pages .

Comment: @lamKarim I have already tried this way, but no way xD.